# Convention for storing reference to this in js

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

Say I need to stick some methods onto an `object` using the `this` keyword, but inside of another function, or inside of a `promise` (for some reason `this` is `undefined` in that context).

Is there a convention for doing this? This is a semantic question as I know all I need to do is essentially `var cachedThis = this;` to make it work.

Is there an existing pattern I can use that a future developer might recognize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many use "self" or "that".  ( as per @LIUFA). As far as "convention", one of those would be best.

Personally, those both feel / read a bit strange to me.  I use a name based upon the class.  For example, if the constructor is Foo, I use

`var foo = this;`

YMMV - I have a Java background, so lowercase class name feels very natural.  If you have a smalltalk or python background you will like "self".

Comment: being js there is no class. :) It's inside of an angular js controller and I ended up using ctrl as that refers to the "this" of the controller. In essence I guess I took your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one that I am using, and I have seen it being used around quite a lot.
'let me take a selfie...'

```
var self = this;
```

I am not sure if this qualifies to be called convention.